# using jquery how to trigger event continually after the given time intervel

Tags: jquery

I need to update given selector continually after the given time intervel. this is my code using javascript.

```
function current_time(){
   var content = document.getElementById('time_div');
   content.innerHTML = '<p> Time is : '+Date()+'</p>';
}

var v = setInterval( 'current_time()', 1000);
```

this is ok. but my question is using jquery can we do that ? I tried this way. it works only one time. how I trigger that event continually after the given time interval(without click event).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#time_div').click(function(){
        $(this).html('<p>'+Date()+'</p>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Please don't ever use `setInterval(string, ...)`. `setInterval('f()', 1000)` is functionally equivalent to `setInterval(f, 1000)` as long as `f` refers to `window.f` and `window.f` doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var v = setInterval(function() {
        $("#time_div").html("<p>" + Date() + "</p>");
    }, 1000);
});
```

To make your original code a little friendlier to read...

```
var v = setInterval(function() {
   document.getElementById("time_div").innerHTML = "<p>" + Date() + "</p>";
}, 1000);
```

Comment: thanks, if you can tell me, what is the best way to that and is there any advantage? @Archer

Comment: @user1784592 What is the best way to what?

Comment: I mean is there any advantages if we use jquery do something ?

Comment: @user1784592 I think just the fact that it's shorter (and therefore easier to read) code is the only advantage to using jQuery for this.  It will be more efficient to use pure JavaScript.

Comment: @user1784592 `$(...).html()` is just a syntactic sugar, but it's still very sweet ;-)

Comment: @user1784592 and also setInterval is a standard JavaScript function, not part of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#time_div').click(function(){
        $(this).html('<p>'+Date()+'</p>');
    });
});

var v = setInterval( function(){$('#time_div').trigger('click')} , 1000);
```

*setInterval* is a standard JavaScript function, not part of jQuery. You call it with a function to execute and a period in milliseconds. e.g:-

```
setInterval(function() {
//Do something every 1 seconds
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Specifying the time as 2000 will call the function every 2 seconds i think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
                    $('#time_div').html('<p>'+Date()+'</p>');
                }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Please don't ever use `setInterval(string, ...)`, even if the asker does.

Comment: Will that cause any problem?

Comment: It uses `eval` internally. Eval is evil. Also, it refers to `window.current_time`, not the local `current_time`. Also, if `window.current_time` changes, the new version will be called instead.

Comment: If you _really_ want the functionality of `setInterval(string, ...)`, you should still stick to anonymous functions for readability as well as performance: `setInterval(function(){window.current_time()})`

Comment: "People, `eval` **starts a compiler**." -- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx